# Why is my logged value correct, but when I return it it is 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have a feeling I am missing an obvious point, but I've tried every way that I know of, and I have also looked into all existing questions concerning the topic (most of which deal with asynchronous calls).

In the following code, I am trying to find the country matching an abbreviation. When I log the result, I get the correct result - but when I return it, I get an `undefined`.

```js
var countries = [
    {value: 'Belgium', data: 'BE'},
    {value: 'France', data: 'FR'},
    {value: 'Bulgaria', data: 'BG'},
    {value: 'Denmark', data: 'DK'},
    {value: 'Croatia', data: 'HR'},
    {value: 'Germany', data: 'DE'},
];
        
function findCountry(code) {
  $.each(countries, function (i, obj) {
    if (obj.data === code) {
      console.log(countries[i]['value']);
      return countries[i]['value'];
    }
  });
}  

var k = findCountry('DE');
alert(k);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Other things I have tried:

```
countries[i].value;
obj.value;
obj['value'];
```

Comment: Your function isn't returning anything, the return is inside the `$.each`, which is not assigned to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` instead of `each` method to return only the targeted element.

[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/find)

```js
var countries = [
    {value: 'Belgium', data: 'BE'},
    {value: 'France', data: 'FR'},
    {value: 'Bulgaria', data: 'BG'},
    {value: 'Denmark', data: 'DK'},
    {value: 'Croatia', data: 'HR'},
    {value: 'Germany', data: 'DE'},
];
        
function findCountry(code) {
 return countries.find(function(c){
    return c.data==code;
 });
}  

var countryObject = findCountry('DE');
console.log(countryObject);
//Get only the value
console.log(countryObject.value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```